# Prove that the map from a set of certian sequences to its limit is a bijection

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose $\mathcal{P}=\big\{\{p_n\}_{n\ge1}:p_n\in\mathbb{Z},p_1\ge2,p_{n+1}\ge p_n^2\big\}$, by monotone convergence theorem, the limit
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{j=1}^n\left(1+\frac{1}{p_j}\right)
$$
converges for every $\{p_n\}_{n\ge1}\in\mathcal{P}$. Moreover, it can be shown that
$$
1<\prod_{j=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac{1}{p_j}\right)\le1+\frac{1}{p_1-1}\le2
$$
Now I am asked to prove that the function $f$ which takes $\{p_n\}_{n\ge1}\in\mathcal{P}$ to $\prod_{j\ge1}(1+1/p_j)$ is a bijection from $\mathcal{P}\to(1,2]$. To show $f$ is an injection, it suffices to show that if there is $m\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ and $p,q\in\mathcal{P}$ such that
$$
p_j=q_j~~(1\le j\le m-1),~~p_{m}<q_{m}
$$
then
$$
\begin{align*}
\prod_{j=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac{1}{q_j}\right)&=\prod_{j=1}^{m-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{q_j}\right)\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{q_{m}}\right)\cdot\prod_{j=m+1}^\infty\left(1+\frac{1}{q_j}\right)\\
&\le\prod_{j=1}^{m-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{p_j}\right)\cdot\frac{1+1/q_{m}}{1-1/q_{m+1}}\\
&\le\prod_{j=1}^{m-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{p_j}\right)\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{q_{m}-1}\right)\\&\le\prod_{j=1}^{m}\left(1+\frac{1}{p_j}\right)<\prod_{j=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac{1}{p_j}\right)
\end{align*}
$$
which implies that $p\neq q\implies f(p)\neq f(q)$. However, I have no idea how to construct a suitable $p\in\mathcal{P}$ for every $y\in(1,2]$ such that $f(p)=y$. Maybe a natural way to do that is define
$$
p_j=\min\left\{p\in\mathbb{Z}:p\ge p_{j-1}^2,\prod_{k=1}^{j-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{p_k}\right)\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right)\le y\right\}
$$
then I only get one inequality $f\big(\{p_{n}\}_{n\ge1}\big)\le y$, and stuck in the other direction. Please help me with that. Thanks a lot!